# Excel Office Online Server - not refreshing CUBEVALUE formula from Office Online Server

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2019, office-online-server

I have a setup with Office Online Server linked to SharePoint 2019. In SharePoint I have uploaded an Excel file with a query connection to an SSAS Cube. I also setup parameters in the Browser View Options of Excel. Then I have a CUBEVALUE formula that depends on one of these parameters. The problem I have is that when I set the parameter in read-only Excel Online, the CUBEVALUE changes to #NA. If I go to Excel edit mode and change the cell linked to the parameter it works correctly. Therefore the problem is only related to setting the parameter while read-only mode. Interestingly if I click 'refresh all connections' while in read-only mode then it works. But I need a way such that when updating the the parameter, the CUBEVALUE refreshes automatically without the user having to click 'refresh all connections'. Is there a way to achieve this?